# Remove string at end of URL

Tags: .htaccess

I can't figure out how to remove the string `{jass_domain_name}/jass/jass.js?cb=47` from the end of my URLs using .htaccess. I've looked through a bunch of responses here and tried all of the following - they either crash the site or give me a js error.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\{jass_domain_name}​/jass​/jass\.js\?cb=47(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)Q\{jass_domain_name}/jass/jass.js?cb=47\E
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+){jass_domain_name}/jass/jass.js?cb=47$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.elearnenglishlanguage.com/blog/%1 [R,L]

RewriteRule ^/(.*)\{(.*) http://www.elearnenglishlanguage.com/blog/$1
```

Thanks in advance for any advice.

ETA my /blog/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.*?)%7Bjass_domain_name%7D/jass/jass\.js\?cb=47\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,NE,R=302]

#WFIPBLOCKS - Do not remove this line. Disable Web Caching in Wordfence to remove this data.
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from 54.74.250.230
Deny from 54.177.48.98
Deny from 54.177.53.123
Deny from 54.170.232.157
#Do not remove this line. Disable Web Caching in Wordfence to remove this data - WFIPBLOCKS
#WFCACHECODE - Do not remove this line. Disable Web Caching in Wordfence to remove this data.
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/json
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddType text/html .html_gzip
    AddEncoding gzip .html_gzip
    AddType text/xml .xml_gzip
    AddEncoding gzip .xml_gzip
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.html_gzip$ no-gzip
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.xml_gzip$ no-gzip
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Vary "Accept-Encoding, Cookie"
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    #Prevents garbled chars in cached files if there is no default charset.
    AddDefaultCharset utf-8

    #Cache rules:
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    RewriteRule .* - [E=WRDFNC_HTTPS:_https]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
    RewriteRule .* - [E=WRDFNC_ENC:_gzip]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?:\d+=\d+)?$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (?:\/|\.html)$ [NC]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(comment_author|wp\-postpass|wf_logout|wordpress_logged_in|wptouch_switch_toggle|wpmp_switcher) [NC]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/*([^\/]*)\/*([^\/]*)\/*([^\/]*)\/*([^\/]*)\/*([^\/]*)(.*)$
    RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/blog/wp-content/wfcache/%{HTTP_HOST}_%1/%2~%3~%4~%5~%6_wfcache%{ENV:WRDFNC_HTTPS}.html%{ENV:WRDFNC_ENC}" -f
    RewriteRule \/*([^\/]*)\/*([^\/]*)\/*([^\/]*)\/*([^\/]*)\/*([^\/]*)(.*)$ "/blog/wp-content/wfcache/%{HTTP_HOST}_blog/$1~$2~$3~$4~$5_wfcache%{ENV:WRDFNC_HTTPS}.html%{ENV:WRDFNC_ENC}" [L]
</IfModule>
#Do not remove this line. Disable Web caching in Wordfence to remove this data -     WFCACHECODE
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress


# prevent comment posting to requests with no referer
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .wp-comments-post\.php*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !.*elearnenglishlanguage.com.* [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$
RewriteRule (.*) ^http://www.elearnenglishlanguage.com/blog/$ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: What is the original URL and what should be final URL?

Comment: It's any url on my site, for example

`http://www.elearnenglishlanguage.com/blog/{jass_domain_name}/jass/jass.js?cb=47`

I want it to remove all of that jass stuff and just go to the real url: `http://www.elearnenglishlanguage.com/blog/`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule as **very first rule** in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.*?)%7Bjass_domain_name%7D/jass/jass\.js\?cb=47\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,NE,R=302]
```

Comment: Thank you, but that still gives me the same error:

    `try {
     console.log("- ERROR - Original site javascript does not exist. This is a placeholder");
    } catch (e) {
    }`

Comment: This is properly tested rule on my Apache. Do you have .htaccess in `/blog/` also?

Comment: Yes, I do. Should I be putting this code in the /blog/ .htaccess instead?

Comment: yes that's right, this rule should be placed as **very first** rule in `/blog/.htaccess`

Comment: I'm getting the same error whether it's in / or /blog/, so clearly there's a bigger problem on my site/server that needs to be figured out first. Thanks for trying.  :-)

Comment: OK, I've added it to my question.

Comment: Yes saw that, you need to insert this rule just below `RewriteBase /` line of `/blog/.htaccess`

Comment: Nope, I still get the console log error. This is a lost cause. Thank you for all of your efforts, but as I said there must be some other issue preventing this from working.

Comment: Yes definitely as that console log also doesn't make since that is all generated by your own code/framework which can be faulty too.